# How to sync grid with pop up editor during editing

Tags: jquery, grid, shieldui

In the following grid, when you start editing using the pop up editor, you don't see the change in grid behind at the same time,how can I do that?
the following grid is the example of SHIELDUI site which could be found at:

http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-editing/popup-editing

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#grid").shieldGrid({
        dataSource: {
            remote: {
                read: "/employees",
                modify: {
                    create: {
                        url: "/employees/EmployeeCreate",
                        type: "post",
                        data: function (edited) {
                            var date = edited[0].data.BirthDate ? edited[0].data.BirthDate.toJSON() : new Date().toJSON();
                            return {
                                Active: edited[0].data.Active,
                                Age: edited[0].data.Age,
                                BirthDate: date,
                                Name: edited[0].data.Name,
                                ID: edited[0].data.ID
                            };
                        }
                    },
                    update: {
                        url: "/employees/EmployeeUpdate",
                        type: "post",
                        data: function (edited) {
                            var date = edited[0].data.BirthDate ? edited[0].data.BirthDate.toJSON() : new Date().toJSON();
                            return { 
                                Active: edited[0].data.Active,
                                BirthDate: date,
                                Age: edited[0].data.Age,
                                Name: edited[0].data.Name,
                                ID: edited[0].data.ID
                            };
                        }
                    },
                    remove: {
                        url: "/employees/EmployeeRemove",
                        type: "post",
                        data: function (removed) {
                            return { ID: removed[0].data.ID };
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            schema: {
                fields: {
                    ID: { path: "ID", type: Number },
                    Name: { path: "Name", type: String },
                    Age: { path: "Age", type: Number },
                    BirthDate: { path: "BirthDate", type: Date },
                    Active: { path: "Active", type: Boolean }
                }
            }
        },
        paging: {
            pageSize: 5
        },
        rowHover: false,
        columns: [
            { field: "Name", title: "Product Name"},
            { field: "Age", title: "Age", width: "100px" },
            { field: "BirthDate", title: "Birth Date", format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" },
            { field: "Active", title: "Active", width: "70px" },
            {
                width: 150,
                title: " ",
                buttons: [
                    { commandName: "edit", caption: "Edit" },
                    { commandName: "delete", caption: "Delete" }
                ]
            }
        ],
        editing: {
            enabled: true,
            mode: "popup",
            confirmation: {
                "delete": {
                    enabled: true,
                    template: function (item) {
                        return "Delete product with name '" + item.Name + "'?";
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        toolbar: [
            {
                buttons: [
                    { commandName: "insert", caption: "Add Product" }
                ],
                position: "top"
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: On the sample URL you gave - http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-editing/popup-editing - it is working perfectly fine. When editing a row using the pop-up editor, the value in the Grid gets updated, and also there is a POST call to the backend to update the value.

Comment: @VladimirGeorgiev thanks for the your answer,but as you see in the provided url,before I press the save button I don't see the changes in the grid,what do you mean by POST?should I change something?to see the update simultaneously?

Comment: The changes should be saved in the Grid only after you click the Save button. if you click the Cancel button, they will not be saved.

Comment: yes,i know that but to make my point better I provide a link for Kendo grid demo,please just do the edit on this demo,field by fiel,at the same time  the grid behind shows you which cells you are editing,just try in out please  http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-popup

Comment: If you are talking about the red indicators in the corners of the updated fields, this is available in batch mode - just set editing.batch: true and see what happens.